# show a label always at the bottom of the page in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, label

In my Silverlight Application , I have a label which contains the copyright information.I want to show the label always at the bottom of the screen in every resolution.

```
<sdk:Label
    Height="28"
    x:Name="label1"
    Width="422"
    Content="Copyright © 2013. All rights reserved." Margin="253,662,252,-41" />
```

with margin I am only able to show it at bottom on my screen.

How to do it?

Comment: What container is your label content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with two [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). One "Stretch" `Height="*"` and the second adaptable to content `Height="Auto"`. Use [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the label :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Main content -->
    </Grid>
    <!-- Put the label in row 1 : Grid.Row="1"-->
    <!-- elastic width :) : HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"-->
    <sdk:Label
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="28"
        x:Name="label1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Content="Copyright © 2013. All rights reserved." />
</Grid>
```